# Change a relative URL to absolute URL in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, url, relative-path, absolute-path

How would I take a file in the application's directory (the same folder the .app is in), and get it's absolute path. Say the relative path is "Data/file.txt," how would I use Objective C to get that as an absolute path? I have the user enter their home folder name, if that is any help.

Please help,

HiGuy

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but a suggestion anyway. As a Mac user, I would find it rude when an application needs to live in a special folder structure. I want to be able to drag one .app into my /Applications folder and be done. I prefer supporting files to go into /Library/Application Support or ~/Library/Application Support. Your case might call for a different solution, but first see if you can adhere to this standard.

Comment: @DanielYankowsky - I can see your point, but putting support files that should otherwise be invisible to the user in the main bundle is actually preferable... It makes it easier to delete the application and all it's related detritus, as well as still allowing the application file to be relocated itself.  Creating support structure (even if in the "proper" place) leaves garbage on uninstall.  Now, user specific data is another story, and ~/Library/... is probably the right place for that kind of stuff.

Comment: @BadPirate The original post didn't seem to be asking how to get resource files from *within* the .app directory, but instead how to get a path to a file *aside* the .app directory. That's what I was recommending against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the location of the running app by doing :

```
NSString * applicationPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

Which will return something like :

```
/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/317CF5C7-57B3-42CE-8DF4-4DD10B070D95/Assignment1a.app
```

Then use `- (NSString *)stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` to chop off the last bit.

Answer (score 14):

I'd use the `NSURL` methods that resolve URLs for me, like so:

```
NSURL * bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
NSURL * file = [NSURL URLWithString:@"../Data/file.txt" relativeToURL:bundle];
NSURL * absoluteFile = [file absoluteURL];
```

The "../" is necessary, because otherwise it'd try to locate the file *inside* your app bundle.  Putting the "../" beforehand will tell it to look in the bundle's containing folder, and not in the bundle itself.  Also, `-[NSBundle bundleURL]` is a 10.6+ API, but it's trivial to replicate the functionality using an `NSURL` convenience method and `-[NSBundle bundlePath]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to concatenate the root folder of the app, with the relative path.  You can get at the app home directory with NSHomeDirectory(), so to get the absolute path you can do something like the following:

```
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString: @"/Data/file.txt"];
```

Comment: Not directly related to your answer, but NSHomeDirectory() actually gave me "/Users/MyUserName/" instead of (path to app). I, instead, used NSHomeDirectory() to automatically get the home directory, without the use of an NSTextField.