# Foundation command line tool, file from arguments

Tags: cocoa, command-line-arguments, nsfilemanager, foundation

I am creating a command line tool in Xcode using the foundation framework and I am confused on the basics of dealing with file paths. The first argument is to be a file (myfile.txt) or file path (./myfile.txt). I want to turn this argument into an absolute path (or URL) for the file. How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change a relative URL to absolute URL in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123725/change-a-relative-url-to-absolute-url-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    if(argc < 2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [file path]\n", argv[0]);
      exit(-1);
    }

    NSURL *f = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]]];
    /* Do something with f */
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will this give me a a full handle to the file myfile.txt if the argument is exactly "myfile.txt"?

Comment: If by "handle" you mean the full path, yes. The process CWD is taken into account. If you want to test this for yourself, do NSLog(@"%@", [f path]) after creating the URL.